# Windows equivalent to UNIX "time" command

Tags: windows, command-line

So, Unix has a `time` command that lets users time their code/other things. I was wondering if the Windows command line has anything similar.

Also, I asked a previous question regarding the Linux command line [here](https://superuser.com/questions/218236/how-to-program-the-linux-command-line-to-run-a-piece-of-code-multiple-time). Can we do the same for Windows? If so, how?

Comment: Windows has the standard cmd.exe but if you want something closer to the linux version get the powershell, its way better.

Comment: I searched for "command time for windows" on google on the first result gives: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673523/how-to-measure-execution-time-of-command-in-windows-command-line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673523/how-to-measure-execution-time-of-command-in-windows-command-line)

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 and I just tried the solution posted above. I get the following error: `Unable to query system performance data (c0000004)`. I googled it and someone else had the exact same problem, but the forum suggests no solution. Thanks for the suggestion anyway. Can someone suggest something for the other part?

Comment: @eff, timeit.exe is for server 2003 and XP AFAIK, I don't think its compatible with 7.

Answer (score 72):

Use Powershell

```
Measure-Command {start-process whateveryouwantexecute -Wait}
```

Edited to your need @efficiencylsBliss:

```
Measure-Command {start-process java -argumentlist "whateverargumentisneeded" -wait}
```

Comment: Here's what I tried: `Measure-Command {java test <inputfile> -Wait}`. I got a list of time-related statistics, but not the output from the code. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @efficiency: You forgot the `start-process` command.

Comment: Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '.\6-8.txt'.
At line:1 char:31
+ Measure-Command {start-process <<<<  java .\dancebattle .\6-8.txt -wait}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand`

Comment: The above is what I got when I tried the command on a file named dancebattle that took the file 6-8.txt as input.

Comment: @efficiencylsBliss i add an example suited to your need, don't forget that you can read about any cmdlet trough the command "man" (which in fact is an alias to get-help)

Comment: I'm trying to measure the time it takes to run a Python script using `Measure-Command {start-process \Python27\python test.py -Wait}`.  This opens up a new cmd window to run the process, but then closes the window when it's done running.  I'd like to see the output of the script as well, so how can I keep the window open?

Comment: @JohnPeterThompsonGarcés use the -NoNewWindow parameter of the start-process cmdlet

Comment: Not ideal for short processes (<0.1s), there's overhead to start-process

Comment: How do I redirect the output while using this method? ie `Measure-Command {start-process -NoNewWindow python myscript.py > out.txt -Wait}` isn't working correctly. It outputs everything to the console

Comment: `Measure-Command` is mostly unusable for performance tracking. It displays time with millisecond resolution, but actually rounds it to seconds. This is BS.

Comment: @kirilloid - what would be the way to do this now?

Comment: Using `Measure-Command  { Start-Process -NoNewWindow -Wait oc version }` (I'm measuring a command 'oc version') will show the output in the same powershell window, and one of the returned measures will be TotalSeconds, which includes 'tick'-level resolution (so in effect much more granular than milliseconds). This is on Windows 10

Comment: This command omits the sub command output, pipe the sub command to out-default to fix the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513650/timing-a-commands-execution-in-powershell

Answer (score 25):

I'm using Win XP, for some reason, `timeit.exe` is not working for me. I found another alternative:  `ptime`:

> [ptime 1.0 - Accurately measure program execution time](http://www.pc-tools.net/win32/ptime/)
>
> ptime will run any specified command and parameters, and measure the execution time (run time) in seconds, accurate to 5 millisecond or better. It is an automatic process timer, or program timer used for benchmark purposes.

Comment: ptime have one small bug. ptime always return 0 as error level, even if "child" program exit with error

Comment: Super simple and accurate output.

Comment: Seems to work fine in Win10.

Answer (score 22):

You can cheat a little with a batch script...

```
@echo off
echo %time% < nul
cmd /c %1
echo %time% < nul
```

Then run your program as an argument to this script...

```
timer myprogram.exe
```

and for arguments...

```
timer "myprogram.exe -sw1 -sw2"
```

example output:

```
17:59:20.02
some text
17:59:20.03
```

place the batch script somewhere in your PATH variable, e.g. `C:\Windows\System32` and name it `timer.cmd`. Of course there is a small performance hit of forking a second cmd instance,  although very minimal.

Comment: that prompt wouldn't work,
`@echo off
echo %time% < nul
cmd /c %1
echo %time% < nul
` you left out the closing % on the environment variable(?)

Comment: There is no closing % for command line parameters like %1. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Why would you redirect `nul` *into* `echo`? `echo` doesn't ever read input.

Comment: You can change `cmd /c %1` to `cmd /c %*`, so that you can save quotation mark for command arguments

Answer (score 10):

For ease of use, here is the chocolatey package:
https://chocolatey.org/packages/ptime

`C:/> choco install ptime`

The advantage if `ptime` is that it acts like the unix version and yields the console output, which `Measure-Command { XXX }` does not (or at least I don't know how to do that).

Answer (score 7):

Some coffee helped me come up with this:

```
function time { $Command = "$args"; Measure-Command { Invoke-Expression $Command 2>&1 | out-default} }
```

And if you want it to output nothing, just replace with out-null:

```
function timequiet { $Command = "$args"; Measure-Command { Invoke-Expression $Command 2>&1 | out-null} }
```

You use it like this:

```
PS C:\> time sleep 5


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 4
Milliseconds      : 990
Ticks             : 49906722
TotalDays         : 5,77624097222222E-05
TotalHours        : 0,00138629783333333
TotalMinutes      : 0,08317787
TotalSeconds      : 4,9906722
TotalMilliseconds : 4990,6722



PS C:\>
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no direct equivalent to Unix `time` on Windows.

The University of Georgia have a brief list of [Windows commands for Unix users](http://www.ai.uga.edu/mc/winforunix.html)

I find the older Windows command prompt and .bat scripting is rather limited compared to Unix shells but there are some facilities for looping over files etc. CommandWindows.com has some [tips](http://commandwindows.com/batchfiles-iterating.htm)

You could either install `bash` on Windows (e.g. by installing CygWin) or learn Windows Powershell (which I am assuming has a means of doing something equivalent).

Answer (score 3):

[gnomon](https://github.com/paypal/gnomon) is a nice solution if you don't only need the total run time of a command, but also line for line measurements:

> A command line utility to prepend timestamp information to the standard output of another command. Useful for long-running processes where you'd like a historical record of what's taking so long.

Installed by running `npm install -g gnomon`, then just use it via `command | gnomon`.

Answer (score 2):

The output for your code can be piped to a file: `java test <inputfile> | Out-File d:\a.txt`

For measuring how long it takes you have to encapsulate it in Measure-Commmand:

`Measure-Commmand {java test <inputfile> | Out-File d:\a.txt}`

Answer (score 2):

If you try to use PowerShell with Measure-Command be aware that there may be some unexpected gotchas. [My command](https://superuser.com/questions/232075/powershell-overruling-perl-binmode) writes binary data to a file using `>` redirection but PowerShell added a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to the beginning of the file and a CRLF line break after every write!

Answer (score 1):

An improvement on [Andrei Ghimus's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1289962/609934).

```
function time {
    $Command = $MyInvocation.Line -Replace ("^$($MyInvocation.MyCommand) ", "")
    Measure-Command { Invoke-Expression $Command | Out-Default }
}
```

The use of `MyInvocation` allows obtaining the actual arguments which is important when the command contains double quotes.

I found the `2>&1` just hid stderr which isn't what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can write C++ code using Windows API to create a utility tool for yourself.

Possible reasons to do so:

- You don't want to use PowerShell.
- You want more control of the `time` program. You may consider falling back to `cmd /c <COMMAND>` if `<COMMAND>` can only be interpreted by `cmd.exe`.
- Normally, utility tools (e.g. `ptime` and MSYS2 `time`) take the process creation time into account. But `Measure-Command` in PowerShell does not. To get a closer estimation, you can record start time after the creating subprocess and before waiting for it. If you do want to include process creation time, just move the line where the start time is recorded.

Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <process.h>

using namespace std::chrono;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "** Error: no command provided\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    printf("Running ");
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
        printf("[%s] ", argv[i]);
    printf("\n");

    auto handle = _spawnvp(_P_NOWAIT, argv[1], &argv[1]);
    if (handle < 0) {
        perror("_spawnv failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    auto start_time = high_resolution_clock::now();
    int status;
    if (_cwait(&status, handle, _WAIT_CHILD) == -1) {
        perror("_cwait failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    auto end_time = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end_time - start_time);
    printf("duration: %lld ms\n", duration.count());
}
```

Assume the utility is `mtime`. Run `mtime mtime` in `cmd`:

```
cmd> mtime mtime
Running [mtime] 
** Error: no command provided
duration: 5 ms
```

The first `mtime` measures the running time of the second `mtime`, which fails fast (and can be considered as a "Hello World" program). Result should be 5 ~ 7 ms, and is so close to `Measure-Command`'s estimation:

```
PowerShell> measure-command{.\mtime|Out-Default}
** Error: no command provided


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 6
Ticks             : 64007
TotalDays         : 7.40821759259259E-08
TotalHours        : 1.77797222222222E-06
TotalMinutes      : 0.000106678333333333
TotalSeconds      : 0.0064007
TotalMilliseconds : 6.4007
```

If you count process creation time, the result should be about 11 ms. (Process creation is much slower on Windows than on Linux.)

Caveats:

- Do not pass `_P_WAIT` to `_spawnvp`. That way, when the subprocess exits with a non-zero code, your measuring program will fail as well (because it cannot tell whether process creation fails or subprocess exits abnormally).
- Use `cl.exe` or `clang++.exe` to compile. Do not use `g++.exe`, because it cannot optimize Windows API as well as the other two. (My `g++` version is `g++ (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project) 11.3.0`, and `clang++` version is `clang version 14.0.0; Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`)
- In PowerShell, `measure-command{<COMMAND>|Out-Default}` takes longer if `<COMMAND>` can only be resolved in `PATH` and your `PATH` is long (for my laptop it takes 14 ms for a "Hello World" exe at the bottom of `PATH`). In cmd, executable files are cached, so consecutive same commands run faster even if full path is not specified.

In my test, the program was compiled with no optimization. If you turn it on, program should be a little bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple different options to get a 'time' command. My preference is to just **install Cygwin** (which comes with a UNIX-like `time` command).

Alternatively, you can write a script and add it to your path (so that you can execute it without specifying the entire path).

If you have **Powershell** available, try this script (works when calling files--'.exe',etc.):

```
$start = get-date
if ($args.length -gt 1) {
start-process $args[0] $args[1..$args.length] -workingdirectory $pwd -nonewwindow -wait
} else {
start-process $args[0] -workingdirectory $pwd -nonewwindow -wait
}
$end = get-date
$elapsed = $end - $start
write-host $end-$start
# datetime format
write-host $elapsed
# easy-to-read format
echo $elapsed
```

Run the code with (for instance):

```
time.ps1 python program.py
```

Using **Batch**, I'd suggest either of the top answers from [here (on Stackoverflow.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739606/how-long-a-batch-file-takes-to-execute). Both just need to be copy-pasted. Note that if you use [paxdiablo's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/739620/1165522), you should replace

```
ping -n 11 127.0.0.1 >nul: 2>nul:
```

with

```
%*
```

Answer (score 0):

After all I decided to create my own implementation of time command for Windows: [pbench.exe](https://github.com/chemodax/pbench)

Notable features:

- Measure CPU time (user and kernel)
- Measure IO operations
- Option to run command multiple times
- Option to run command multiple times concurrently
- Option to measure another running process (useful for services)

For example to measure performance of `curl http://example.com command`:

```
pbench --stdout-nul curl http://example.com

==== curl http://example.com ====

== Performance of curl http://example.com
   Real time:    0.299 s
    CPU time:    0.015 s
   User time:    0.000 s
 Kernel time:    0.015 s
     Read IO:        0 (       0 KB)
    Write IO:        1 (       1 KB)
    Other IO:      127 (       1 KB)
Peak WS size:     6196 KB

  Total time:    0.303 s
```

The utility is completely free and open-source:
https://github.com/chemodax/pbench