# Powershell overruling Perl binmode?

Tags: windows, powershell, perl, binary-files, crlf

I have a Perl script which creates a binary file while scanning a very large text file. It outputs to STDOUT which I redirect in the commandline to a file.

To optimize it I'm making changes then seeing how low it takes to run. On Linux for this I use the "time" command. On Windows the best way to time a program seemed to be to PowerShell's "measure-command". This seemed to work fine but I noticed the generated files were larger. On examination I found that the files generated from within PowerShell begin with a BOM and contain CRLF pairs!

My Perl script has a "binmode STDOUT" directive and does work correctly in a normal dosbox.

Is this a bug or misfeature in PowerShell or measure-command? Has it affected others creating binary files by means other than Perl?

Googling hasn't turned anything up so far. I'm using Perl 5.12, PowerShell v1.0 and Windows XP.

Comment: Not a real answer... you may want to ask this on stackoverflow.

Comment: Yeah it was tough deciding which site to ask on. I went with this one because it was more about the features of the tools than algorithsm or data structures but I'll move it if nobody answers here (-:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because PowerShell will see the output as strings by default.  Strings in .NET are Unicode, so that is the default output of PowerShell.

I assume that you are using PowerShell to write the output to a file?  If so, then using "Set-Content -Encoding Byte" will fix your issue.

```
Measure-Command {& "c:\myscript.pl" | Set-Content "C:\myoutput.bin" -Encoding Byte}
```

Comment: So | Set-Content "C:\myoutput.bin" is like > "C:\myoutput.bin" under DOS or Unix with the pipe character used also for redirection?

Comment: Its the pipe character and is used the same way as DOS and Unix shells.  In this case you use Set-Content so that we can use the Byte encoding.